Maven не находит путь к классу Main
В рамках отработки навыков работы с Maven составил блок, благодаря подсказкам, ошибки пропали. Но при запуске в терминале java -jar target/JavaStart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
вылетает сообщение:
Could not find or load main class Main
вот мой Maven:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaStart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Замените на ваш класс с методом main -->
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно указывать путь?
<manifest>
                            <!-- Замените на ваш класс с методом main -->
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
</manifest>

У меня просто  класс Main с методом main.
Или в пути нужно указать путь до локальной папки на компьютере?

Указывать нужно не путь к папке, а полное имя класса, включающее название пакета.  В каком пакете ваш класс Main?

Я не знаю в каком пакете мой класс main. Как это узнать, куда глянуть? Про пакеты я еще ничего не изучал.

Пакеты в Java (Package). Как понимать и использовать?


В строчке
<mainClass>Main</mainClass>попробуйте указать полное расположение класса, например: <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
Попробуйте создать package и переместить в него класс Main, не забывая указать полное расположение класса в конфигурации Maven, в самом классе должно быть указание на пакет, например: package example


Да действительно, нужно было указать org.example.Main.
так все заработало. Благодарю.
